# Suggestions on staying dry without an eruv on shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, weather, how-to

What are some suggestions on staying dry in the rain without an eruv on shabbos?

1. Wearing a raincoat?

   - Is there any issue with wearing more than one coat at a time and also removing it when it is wet which could be wringing out water similar to the problem presented by swimming and taking off a wet bathing suit?
2. Having an attachment umbrella for one's hat or covering it with plastic?
3. Any other ideas I haven't thought of...

Comment: How does the absence of an eruv affect the problem?

Comment: Dude -- I assumed we're discussing rain....if I'm wrong just fix it [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/45829/edit).

Comment: Why would taking off a dry coat covered in water be "washing" it?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin perhaps you might accidentally "squeeze" it? Especially if it does not juse shake off and stay dry.

Answer (score 3):

If you wear a hat, you can use a [Shayne Coat](http://www.eichlers.com/shaynecoat-raincoat-polyester-full-coverage-clothes-and-hat.html), which will cover your clothes and your hat.
(there are also shtreimel models of the coat)

Comment: This answer seems somewhat geared toward men. What about women?

Comment: I wouldn't know, personally.....

Comment: @Daniel Over Yom Tov, I saw women wearing Shayne Coats (though without a hat, just the tremendous hood). _Now_ is my answer only for men? :P

Answer (score 2):

A hat with a brim can keep your head and shoulders fairly dry in a light rain (but won't help with wind).  [Hats with a brim of a *tefach* or more might be a problem](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27914/759) (h/t, err, to DoubleAA), so seek halachic guidance.  This does assume that you will take the hat off when you arrive or that you don't care about it being wet, so if all you require is a kippah you're good but it won't help if you wear a hat indoors and want it to stay dry.  For that case, see [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/45831/472).

For the rest of you, a raincoat or waterproof poncho does a decent job of keeping you dry.  You would shed any outer coat upon arriving at your destination anyway, so I don't see why you'd need a second one.  (That would only seem to be a concern if your outer coat absorbed water.)  I see people doing this sometimes to avoid using an umbrella.  Some of them even [have hoods](http://www.target.com/p/totes-rain-poncho-navy/-/A-14594112).

Comment: This answer seems somewhat geared toward men. What about women?

Comment: As a woman I wear a hat with a brim when the weather calls for it, and I also have a water-resistant light coat (so I don't personally need a poncho, though I've seen others use them).  I guess the hat part of this doesn't work for women who wear a dress hat (that they don't want to get wet), as opposed to a scarf.