# Yarmulke fell off outside of the eiruv?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, kippa-yarmulka, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot

This past Shabbos, I was walking with some friends for an *aufruf* in another part of town. Where we started from had an *eiruv*, and where we were going had an *eiruv*, but there was an area in between that did not have an *eiruv*. This area actually has a shot at being a *reshus harabim*, as it's a highway that has *many* cars driving through it on a regular basis (though I'd have to check if it actually *is* a *reshus harabim*).

While we were walking through the stretch that didn't have an *eiruv*, my friend's *yarmulke* blew off. I didn't tell him anything, but he picked it up and put it back on.

So now I'm wondering what actually should have been done. Since it might make a difference:

- What should have been done, assuming the highway was a Biblical *reshus harabim* (רשות הרבים דאורייתא)?
- What should have been done, assuming that the highway was **not** a רשות הרבים דאורייתא?

Answer (score 8):

Even in a real public domain one can carry things within 4 Amot. (ShA OC 349)

So he was allowed to pick it up and put it on. Then he's wearing it and can continue walking.

([Though he might not have been allowed to wear it without enough clips to begin with...](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/27980/759))

Comment: Even derabanan?

Comment: @andrewmh20 I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: It just sounded surprising to me that even derabanan one is allowed to carry less than 4 amot.

Comment: @andrewmh20 On the contrary! What else is someone stuck there supposed to do? You sit tight, eat your food and play solitaire.

Comment: If he might not have been allowed to have worn it to start with -- specifically, if he wasn't allowed to -- then how can you say he's allowed to now? +1, though.

Comment: You don't address two issues here that may bear addressing, though the answers may be obvious. 1, is the transfer off the ground _akira_ into his hand (and the placing on his head a continuation thereof) and only his subsequent removal of the yarmulke when he reaches his destination a _hanacha_ of it, which thus effects transfer between domains? 2, is his lifting into his hand _akira_ and placement on his head _hanacha_ in a different domain?

Comment: @msh210 1) I meant he can now assuming he could to begin with 2a) Standing still is a full hanacha. 2b) A human is part of the reshut he's standing in. Otherwise you could carry over your head because it's ten tefachim off the ground.