# Where can I buy a Yeshivish fedora online?

Tags: product-recommendation, clothing, internet, black-hats

In most [Yeshivish][1] circles (and Chabad Hasidim), a black snap-brim fedora is worn. Usually it is a Borsalino, but not always. Could someone recommend a place online where I could get one or one like it for a relatively cheap price? Preferably under $200 or so.

---

**Update:**

I ended up purchasing from [Yeshivish Hats][2], and I must say that I am extremely impressed with the quality of the product. It is literally identical to the Borsolinos, except they're made by a Ben Torah instead of some Italian company.

I received the hat this past Shabbos (it was so hard to wait!) and opened it after Havdalah and I was immediately impressed. The hat was packed very nicely, to ensure that it would not become damaged during transit from Greece, NY to my humble home in West Texas. Included with the hat was a plastic cup and fridge magnet, both with their logo on it (so you're drinks and fridge can be Yeshivish too). I was expecting to have to take the hat to a local hat shop to get the brim shaped, but actually it snapped straight into the famous down-turn when I pulled on the brim!

Comment: Is this on topic?

Comment: Watch out for that hat brim size, maybe. See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27914/5275

Comment: @mevaqesh See [tag:product-recommendation]. The community seems to be okay with very specific Judaism-related shopping questions. (I thought there was a meta post about this, but can't find it right now.)

Comment: @Shokhet There is of course. The not clearly resolved question is what defines ti as Judaism related...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've never used them, but friends of mine have ordered from https://www.yeshivishhats.com/. The home page says that their price is $55.

Comment: (Interestingly if you notice on his site, he actually checks his hats for shatnez since they are made from sheeps wool. Most hats this style are rabbit fur which don't need to be checked.)

Answer (score 4):

[This hat](http://www.bencrafthats.com/brands/puertofino/giorgio-by-puertofino-hats) is available for $145 on [bencrafthats.com](http://bencrafthats.com). You can probably find other hats from them for relatively cheap prices.

Answer (score 1):

Ashernewyork.com is running their grand opening sale and selling their wool hats reg. 65.99 for only 36$ and free shipping!!
Great for bar mitzvah boys starter hats or weekday hats can't go wrong for 36$ order while supplies last!!

Comment: Ashernewyork.com is a bit more stylish offering a smaller 6cm brim

Comment: Thank you for the link, Shawn K, and welcome to Mi Yodeya! I prefer a larger brim for my hats but I know many people who like small brims, so this is a great resource. :)